# wp_remote_get vs. file_get_contents vs. cURL?

Tags: curl, wp-remote-get

I need to fetch the contents of a remote file. Which is better for performance - wp_remote_get, file_get_contents, or cURL?

How exactly does wp_remote_get work? Can you suppress errors, ex. @wp_remote_get ?

Thanks

Comment: If you get errors, then please add the details of the errors to your question. Half a question is no question at all.

Answer (score 5):

Always use wp_remote_get when in a WordPress context. It figures out the correct way, be it curl or something else, and uses that. Simple.

Comment: Is it possible to supress errors with an '@' like other functions? Also, is it possible that wp_remote_get is not allowed on a server, but file_get_contents is allowed? How could I go about writing a function that uses file_get_contents if wp_remote_get gives an error? Thanks!

Comment: To elaborate the HTTP API uses `$request_order = array( 'curl', 'streams', 'fsockopen' );` so curl first if that fails streams then fsockopen. Errors are up to you how you handle them.

Comment: Without more information on the error, it's impossible to answer your question in any more detail. Make your question more explicit and clear. Additionally, you don't want to use file_get_contents, because that won't work on a majority of webhosts. If you get an error, then tell us the error so that we can give you correct information instead of guessing randomly at your problem.